# Error while compiling linuxsampler in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-installation, 19.10

Following [this tutorial](http://linuxsampler.org/debian.html), and after installing flex (that solved a previous compiling error), I ran:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

But I get an error message that contains the words:

```
no rule to make target 'parser.h'
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, just open the source code main folder and run:

```
make parser
```

this will solve the dependency and allow the compiling process to finish.